# How can I make my nav bar go through my System Nav bar

Tags: flutter, dart

This is my nav bar theme data

```
 navigationBarTheme: NavigationBarThemeData(
        backgroundColor: Color(0xff0100f5b),
        indicatorColor: Color(0xff5454c2),
        labelTextStyle: MaterialStateProperty.all(const TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 14,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        )),
        iconTheme: MaterialStateProperty.all(const IconThemeData(
          color: Color(0xffffffff),
          size: 25,
        )),
      ),
```

This is my SystemChrome code

```
SystemChrome.setSystemUIOverlayStyle(SystemUiOverlayStyle(
    statusBarColor: Colors.transparent,
    systemStatusBarContrastEnforced: true,
    statusBarBrightness: Brightness.light,
    systemNavigationBarContrastEnforced: true,
    systemNavigationBarColor: Colors.transparent,
  ));
```

And this is how it looks.

[image: This is how it looks]

I can't understand why can't it go down like the app bar goes up through the status bar.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Just wrap the `BottomNavigationBar` with this

```
return SafeArea(
  bottom: true,
  child: BottomNavigationBar(...),
)
```

Comment: Still doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Did you forget to put in Scaffold?

Comment: No, i haven't forgot. But i fixed it with just making the system nav bar the same color as the nav bar.